# How to add new instrumented methods to intelliJ auto-complete?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, instrumentation, bytecode-manipulation, javaagents

Is it possible to force intelliJ to be aware of new methods/fields (while you type) added to classes through byte-code class redefinition from a java agent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by writing an IntelliJ plugin that would provide information about the generated methods/fields to the internal code analysis infrastructure. This can be accomplished through the [PsiAugmentProvider](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-psi-api/src/com/intellij/psi/augment/PsiAugmentProvider.java) interface.